# How to show 3 dots at the end of text in textview

Tags: android, textview

I know this question is asked many times, i have gone through all the solutions but still the problem is same.

i want my text length to be of 50 characters. now it is coming in 2 lines.

Below is what i did:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notification_Message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/notification_head"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLength="50"
            android:text=" Hello developer. please check this message for long length. max length to 50 characters. "   

            android:textSize="20sp" />
```

The text here is just a sample text i have added. it is not showing 3 dots at end rather showing message upto 50 characters. i have tried **max lines** also, **single line false** also. but no positive result.
I also don't want to handle this thing programmatically by adding three dots logically.

Please help

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Make a preset width for your TextView and add these attributes (Shout-out to @T-D)

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

The maxLines will make sure that your text wont be shown in two lines and the ellipsize will add the three dots in the end.

***Old Answer***

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: `android:singleLine="true"` is deprecated now. Use `android:maxLines="1"` instead.

Comment: I found that at android 4.4.2, it only shows one dot. Is it usual or something

Answer (score 40):

For one line text with a dot but now it's **Deprecated** so don't use `singleLine` anymore

Thanks to this post I found that how to show dot after the end of text if we have more one line, it works for me :)

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="2"
```

**Post here this answer because all answer here are for single line not for multiline**

Answer (score 13):

`android:ellipsize` will works only with:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

or

```
android:maxLines="#any number#"

android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Because maxLength truncate the text.

So you have to manage the label with code if you want to display only 50 char + dots, or let two line for the textview.

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="Hello developer. please check this message for long length. max length to 50 characters."
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: What if i want max characters to be 50

Comment: Recap:
- the text view must display 50 char independently the screen is portrait or landscape.
- no matter if the text are in 2 or 3 lines
- if the text is more than 50 char the dots must appear
- if you use ellipsize the maxLanght cut the dots

The only way i see is:

`String toCut = "Hello developer. please check this message for long length. max length to 50 characters.";
        if(toCut.length() > 50){
            toCut = toCut.substring(0, 50) + '…';
        }
        textView.setText(toCut);`

Comment: i know this can be done. but later i need to getText from this texview. then again it will create a mess for me

Comment: you could store the entire text with setTag(entireText) and later getTag()

Comment: It doesn't scroll in my case

Answer (score 7):

The `android:singleLine="true"` is deprecated

better use

**`android:maxLines="1"`**

and **`android:ellipsize="end"`** to add **"..."** at the end of text

Comment: Any idea how to mange the ellipsize in the middle of a very_long_word without whitespace? It seems to break at whitespaces instead of myVeryLongWord...

Answer (score 4):

Use `singleLine = "true"`
 for limit text by singleLine

Comment: 50 characters could not be represented in single line

Comment: The thing is...singleLine is deprecated, but I could not find a way to make ellipsize work without singleLine = true when I tried it some time ago.

Comment: If you need to show exactly 50 characters , You should apppend 3 dots at the end and change the limit to 53 through code

Comment: You can read it regularly, and I could swear I read it in the docs, but it's no longer stated there. This was the text that used to be there:http://androidsbs.blogspot.co.at/2013/12/deprecated-androidsingleline-set.html

Comment: @PankajKumar Right, should have checked the docs first. But do you know where this rumour about `singleLine` being deprecated comes from? Also, as far as I remember, it was marked as deprecated in the IDE.

Comment: That article was what I found after googling for `android:singleLine deprecated`. I never used it before and always go with the docs if I don't know something. And I only googled it because I remembered the IDE highlighting it as deprecated.

Comment: @PankajKumar Now have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine

Answer (score 4):

I too was struggling with this. `android:maxLength` wasn't having any effect so I played around with `android:maxWidth` and it worked.

Checkout my snippet below.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_comment_author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="@string/dummy_text"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

The approach of @Lokesh works fine.

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="2"
```

But I realize a trouble that TextView will be truncated by word (in default). Show if we have a text like:

***test long_line_without_any_space_abcdefgh***

the TextView will display:

***test...***

And I found solution to handle this trouble, replace spaces with the unicode no-break space character, it makes TextView wrap on characters instead of words:

```
yourString.replace(" ", "\u00A0");
```

The result:

***test long_line_without_any_space_abc...***

Answer (score 1):

Create your customize TextView:

```
<com.xyz.CustomizedTextViewName
        android:id="@+id/app_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxEms="10"

        app:typeface="roboto_bold"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer that you want:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxWidth="195dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

If `singleLine="true"` is depricated in **xml**,still you want to use single line behaviour then use `tv.setSingleLine(true);` method in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt__customizer_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=" Hello developer. please check this message for long length. max length to 50 characters. "
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/light_blue"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
```

This is working for me.give padding from right side.it will automatically shows ...

Comment: Dear, The problem is 50 characters cannot come in one line. Then how can we set single line to true

Comment: then you have use 2 lines for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by `xml`:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:maxLines="1" // or any number of lines you want
    android:ellipsize="end" />
```